# Polar Protic and Aprotic Solvents

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, reaction-mechanism, solvents

I know $\mathrm{S_N2}$ is favored polar aprotic solvents, which means that they may have hydrogens on them somewhere, but they lack $\ce{O-H}$ or $\ce{N-H}$ bonds, and therefore cannot hydrogen bond with themselves.

But I found that $\mathrm{S_N2/E2}$ is favored by $\ce{OH-, RO-}$ (a strong base); if I look at $\ce{OH-}$, doesn't it contain $\ce{O-H}$ and form hydrogen bonds?

Can someone please explain what aprotic solvents then?
Are aprotic solvents a strong base?
What's the difference between  aprotic solvents and a strong base?

[image: Reference]

Comment: OH- in what solvent? Powdered KOH in THF reacts in a very different way from KOH in MeOH.

Comment: This was not mentioned .